# SQLite database value compare with spinner list item and set that value as first item in spinner

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

Customer name is stored in the SQLite database table. I need to compare that customer name with spinner item list. If that name matches in spinner list, then start the list from that name.
Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

try this,
java

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
Spinner spinner;
ArrayList<String> spinner_arr = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayAdapter aa;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    spinner_arr.add("John");
    spinner_arr.add("Tom");
    spinner_arr.add("Kelly");
    spinner_arr.add("Sandy");

    spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    aa = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, spinner_arr);
    spinner.setAdapter(aa);


}
 //check customer name is available in sqlite db
public void compareClick(View view) {
    //fetch sqlite data here(like customer name),suppose customer name is 'Tom'
    String db_cust_name = "Tom";
    for (int i = 0; i < spinner_arr.size(); i++) {
        if (db_cust_name.equals(spinner_arr.get(i))) {
            spinner_arr.subList(0, i).clear();
            aa.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}}
```

xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"/>


<Button
    android:onClick="compareClick"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Compare" />
```

let me know if you need more clarification.